# Aligning layout to fit all screen size

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

> This is my linear layout and i have achieved the following.. I want to consume full page height.So I am taking the weight of the layout.But images are getting stretched

[image]

> But the images are getting stretched.. I want to use the original
>   width of the image.. What changes do i need to make ??

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mdfooter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mdtlone"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/breakfastview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mealbreakfast"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvrequiredbreakfast"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/breakfastactual"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/newbuttonshape"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="gotoCalorieMealsDiaryActivity"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lunchview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/meallunch"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvrequiredlunch"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lunchactual"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/newbuttonshape"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="gotoCalorieMealsDiaryActivity"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dinnerview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mealdinner"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvrequireddinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dinneractual"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/newbuttonshape"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="gotoCalorieMealsDiaryActivity"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/snackview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mealsnacks"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvrequiredsnacks"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/snacksactual"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/newbuttonshape"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="gotoCalorieMealsDiaryActivity"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#E8E8E8" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Total"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#4CC1D2"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/calorieoutput"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/newbuttonshape"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Please suggest anything

Comment: Check [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: I tried it my friend ..

Comment: dont give weight to your imageview instead of give wrapcontent

Comment: replace that `ImageView` with a `LinearLayout` with `weight` = 1 and `height`, `width` as `match_parent`. Place your `ImageView` inside that `LinearLayout` and give its `height`, `weight` as `wrap_content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chnage background to src     "android:src="@drawable/mealbreakfast""

```
               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/breakfastview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/mealbreakfast"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:scaleType="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Design as per below you will be able to solve your problem.

**I changed here for only one ImageView you will do the same in others ImageView.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/mdfooter"
android:layout_below="@+id/mdtlone"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/breakfastview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/mealbreakfast"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:scaleType="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvrequiredbreakfast"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breakfastactual"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/newbuttonshape"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="gotoCalorieMealsDiaryActivity"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lunchview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/meallunch"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvrequiredlunch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lunchactual"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/newbuttonshape"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="gotoCalorieMealsDiaryActivity"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dinnerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mealdinner"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvrequireddinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dinneractual"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/newbuttonshape"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="gotoCalorieMealsDiaryActivity"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/four"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/snackview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mealsnacks"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvrequiredsnacks"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snacksactual"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/newbuttonshape"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="gotoCalorieMealsDiaryActivity"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/five"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#E8E8E8" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Total"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#4CC1D2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calorieoutput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/newbuttonshape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here Your ImageView was Stretched so I replaced the

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/breakfastview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/mealbreakfast"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:scaleType="center" />
```

with my code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/breakfastview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/mealbreakfast"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:scaleType="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

***This will not stretch your ImageView and it looks as it is.***

Hope this will be helpful... Thanks